# Scikit-Learn: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have 2 nominal values of a product (category and producer) and its price and try to identify if in any given category a producer has usually a higher price. In another word, I try to measure the impact of a brand on price. I used below Python code and couldn't manage to run and get this error:

```
Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead.
```

Could you please help me to resolve this?

```
# Load dataset
path = "Sales.xlsx"
names = ['Category', 'Producer', 'Average_base_price']
dataset = read_excel(path, dtype={'Average_base_price':float} ,names=names)

# creating instance of labelencoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

array = dataset.values

# Split-out validation dataset
X, y = array[:, :-1], array[:, -1]

X[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
X[:, 1] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []

for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the whole error message? So that we know which line or which function cause the problem. Also, can you show the first 10 elements of `y` variable? You are using `LogisticRegression` but your `Average_base_price` seems like a continuous variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because your dependent variable is continuous and you are trying to do a stratified kfold which doesn't make sense

If it is like you said:

> In another word, I try to measure the impact of a brand on price.

Then your dependent variable should be price. Your independent variables would be the nominal values. And you should do one-hot encoding instead of label encoding because these are not predictors, not labels.

Using an example dataset:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Category':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],100),
'Producer':np.random.choice(['l','m','n'],100),
'Average_base_price':np.random.uniform(0,1,100)})
```

Onehot encode the predictor:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = enc.fit_transform(dataset[['Category','Producer']])
y = dataset[['Average_base_price']]

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
```

Then fit the model, in this case you can use for example a simple linear regression:

```
model = LinearRegression()
cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=10)
```